# Rational points on projective varieties: what is density?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-varieties

**Dsiclaimer:** this is a very basic question, but many books just skip this crucial point.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety defined over a number field $K$. A closed point  $x\in X$ is said rational if $k(x)=K$. Let $X(K)$ be the set of rational points of $X$.

> What does it mean to check the ``density'' of $X(K)$? Dense where?

My guess is that we consider the base extension $X_{\mathbb C}:=X\times_{K}\mathbb C$ and then we check the density of $X(K)$ in $X_{\mathbb C}$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

A scheme $X$ has an underlying topological space $|X|$. When one asks whether the $k$-points are dense, one usually refers to density as a subset of $|X|$.

Comment: Yes by topology on a scheme I mean the topology on the topological space.

Comment: $|X|$ already has a topology - it's part of the data of $X$. This information is already specified.

Comment: A Variety over $k$ is a $k$-scheme. What is the ground field that we are considering? Is it  $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Presumably it's $K$. ($\Bbb C$ is a bad choice because the residue field at a closed point of a scheme of finite type over $\Bbb C$ is again $\Bbb C$, so you won't have any $K$-points for $K$ a number field.) It may also be worth pointing out that sometimes people use "defined over $K$" to mean that your variety is a $k$-variety for some $k\supset K$ but is defined using equations with coefficients in $K$ - that is, it's a base extension from $K$ to $k$ of some $K$-variety.

Comment: Ok maybe I got it. Let's consider the definition of an $F$-point as a morphism (for  $K\subset F$), then $X(K)\subset X(\mathbb C)=X_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C)$. The latter set can be seen as a projective algebraic set. So we can consider  $X(K)$ dense in $X_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C)$ with respect to the Zariski topology.

Comment: Why are you so insistent on talking about $X(\Bbb C)$? If your question is "can I check whether $X(K)\subset X$ is dense by checking whether $X(K)\subset X(\Bbb C)$ is dense", you should ask that instead - the phrase "$X(K)$ is dense in $X$" means that $X(K)$ is dense in the topological space $|X|$, as I have already explained.

Comment: Yes maybe I have to explain a bit more: I was reading some surveys about the Lang-Bombieri conjecture, and they deal with the "Zariski density" of points inside varieties  in $\mathbb P^n$. I was trying to picture those questions with  in the framework of scheme theory.

Comment: You can do this without saying anything about $X(\Bbb C)$. As you have said, a variety is a scheme, which means you already have a topology on the underlying set to answer the question "what topology do we ask for these points to be dense in?".